# Multiple selects ordering desc from single table

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to do multiple selects to give multiple ordered columns.  I'm struggling to get the below mysql query to achieve the output I want.

SQLfiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1002/3

Table of example data table, veh_summary :

```
veh_id    fac_id   item_id    w_name    stat
   1        1         51      name1      45
   1        1         52      name2      10
   1        1         53      name3      2
   1        2         51      name1      28
   1        2         52      name2      17
   1        2         53      name3      67
   1        3         51      name1      0
   1        3         52      name2      44
   1        3         53      name3      33
   2        1         51      name1      26
```

Output I want where each multiple select are ordered desc with limit:

```
item_id_1   w_name_1   stat_1   item_id_2   w_name_2   stat_2 
    51        name1      45         53        name3      67
    52        name2      10         51        name1      28
```

I'm trying this query:

```
select a.item_id as item_id_1, a.w_name as w_name_1, a.stat as stat_1,
   b.item_id as item_id_2, b.w_name as w_name_2, b.stat as stat_2
from
  (select item_id, w_name, stat from veh_summary 
      where veh_id = 1 and fac_id = 1 ) a,
  (select item_id, w_name, stat from veh_summary 
      where veh_id = 1 and fac_id = 2 ) b 
  order by stat_1 desc, stat_2 desc limit 2
```

But get this output where the first select is not ordering desc:

```
item_id_1   w_name_1   stat_1   item_id_2   w_name_2   stat_2 
    51        name1       45        53         name3     67
    51        name1       45        51         name1     28
```

I'm sure this is simple to do, I've also tried the order by limit in the select itself.  I've done a bit of searching through the questions but don't seem to see one that fits what i'm looking for.

Comment: This is simple to do, true, with window functions and a `FULL` join. MySQL has neither.

Comment: Hmmm ok then, that's annoying...i'm going to have to figure out another way to do this. Thanks for the reply ypercube.

Comment: The simplest would be to run 2 queries and combine the results in the application layer. It can be done in MySQL but it won't be very pretty.